# Hot water tank leak on to the burner

Tags: water-heater, hot-water, leaking

I have recently drained my hot water tank as part of yearly maintenance which I have done it once after I bought this house a year ago. I see this morning water leak on to the burner made burner go off, so I have turned it off at valve and shut the gas inlet to burner. I emptied the tank no leak and then when cold water starts coming in, it leaks again. What could be the reason ? Please let me know.
Water heater is A.O. Smith
Model FSG 50 248

Comment: Where is the leak from? Does it leak if the tank is full but the gas is off?

Comment: It leaks soon the cold water starts coming in when tank is empty. I shut the gas off. And I don't know the exact location of leakage but the water is dripping on to burner

Comment: Any idea how old the water heater is?

Comment: As soon as water comes in + onto the burner = leak in the bottom of the tank. If the tank is more than a few years old, start shopping.

Comment: I personally doubt the benefit of draining a tank. If the leak is from the drain valve, maybe you could get that replaced or maybe unscrew the valve, clean threads, reapply thread sealer and replace the valve.

Comment: No the leak is not from drain valve. How can I figure out the year.. I don't see any such info on heater and don't have papers too. Serial number is MC02-1540936-248

Comment: Keep in mind that while this is a DIY forum and we generally recommending learning skills and doing things yourself, gas is a bit trickier than water and in some jurisdictions you may not be *allowed* to do your own gas. That being said, depending on the plumber (and not all plumbers do gas, obviously you need one that does) you may be able to save $ by doing some of the work yourself, removing the old tank, bringing in the new tank, etc. (Did all that once, the most recent time had trouble finding a local plumber who was available and did gas and paid the price $$$ they charged.)

Comment: Even after I turn cold water off, I hear the droplets sound in the tank.. could this be water inlet problem too ?

Comment: When you say the valve is not leaking are you sure it is not leaking from the threads where it screws into the tank or from the stem? Since you did manipulate the valve to drain the tank, and then got a leak, carefully check that the valve is not leaking. Water *could* leak from the valve threads or the stem, run down the side of the tank under the insulation to the bottom and drip from there.

Comment: You could add a safe leak-detection dye, such as sodium fluorescein, to the water in the tank, and shine an ultraviolet light on the tank and fittings. Yes, this is a bit of a nuisance to do, but if all else has failed in finding the link, it might be worth it.